# Extracting HDD interface type with using DeviceIoControl()

Tags: c++, windows

I need to extract HDD interface type: in the result I need to get, for example, SATA-II.
I tried to use `DeviceIoControl()` and `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` with `STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR -> BusType`:

```
typedef enum _STORAGE_BUS_TYPE {
BusTypeUnknown = 0x00,
BusTypeScsi = 0x1,
BusTypeAtapi = 0x2,
BusTypeAta = 0x3,
BusType1394 = 0x4,
BusTypeSsa = 0x5,
BusTypeFibre = 0x6,
BusTypeUsb = 0x7,
BusTypeRAID = 0x8,
BusTypeiScsi = 0x9,
BusTypeSas = 0xA,
BusTypeSata = 0xB,
BusTypeSd = 0xC,
BusTypeMmc = 0xD,
BusTypeVirtual = 0xE,
BusTypeFileBackedVirtual = 0xF,
BusTypeMax = 0x10,
BusTypeMaxReserved = 0x7F
} STORAGE_BUS_TYPE, *PSTORAGE_BUS_TYPE;
```

but in this case I got `BusTypeAta` value, however, the interface type of the installed hard disk there is **SATA-II**.
Which structures and control codes for `DeviceIoControl()` should I use to get HDD interface type? (WMI do not offer)
Thanks!

Comment: BusTypeSata is win7 onwards only so the driver must new enough/honourable enough to support this. SATA in PATA mode would cause BusTypeAta also.

Comment: OK. So how I can get "SATA-II" value in other way? It must work on XP and 7.